# How to claim $f(x_0) = 1$ and $f(Z) = 0$ in the ans given below

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Z$ be a proper subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $X$, and let $x_0 \in X \setminus Z$.
Show that there is a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x_0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for
all $x \in Z$.

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $Z$ be
an $m$-dimensional subspace of $X$, with $m<n$. Choose a basis $A = \left\{z_1,\ldots,z_m\right\}$ of $Z$, here we can obtain a basis $B = \left\{z_1,\ldots,z_m, z_{m+1},\ldots,z_n\right\}$ of $X$ with $z_{m+1} = x_0$. Any $x \in X$ can be
written uniquely as
$x = α_1z_1 + \ldots + α_m z_m + α_{m+1}x_0 + α_{m+2}z_{m+2} + \ldots + α_nz_n$.
Consider the linear functional
$f : X \to K$ defined by $f(x) = α_{m+1} + \ldots + α_{n}$,
where $α_j$ is the $j$-th scalar of $x$ with respect to the basis $B$ for all $j = m+1,\ldots,n$.
Then how can we claim that
$f(x_0) = 1$ and $f(Z) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Just put $a_{m+1}=1$ and all other $a_i$'a equal to $0$ in the definition of $f$ to see that $f(x_0)=1$. For $x$ in $Z$ note that $a_i=0$ for all $i >m$ and hence $f(x)=0$.